# Src unknown after push

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, image

Hi i have problem with pushing item from one array to another. It's system of equipment in my game. The problem is that image of item has unknown src after being pushed to another array.

angular ts

```
  itemy = [{id: 0, name: "sword", url:'../../../../assets/img/sword.png'}, {id: 1, name: "sword2", url:"../../../../assets/img/sword2.png"}];
  images = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('images')) || [];
  add (){
    let index=Math.round(Math.random())
    this.images.push(this.itemy[index]);
    localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(this.images));
  }

  eq = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('eq')) || [];
  select() {
    this.eq.push(this.images);
    this.eq.length = 1;
    localStorage.setItem('eq', JSON.stringify(this.eq));
  }
  unselect() {
    this.eq.pop();
    localStorage.setItem('eq', JSON.stringify(this.eq));
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="eq">
  <div id="contentInside2" *ngFor="let image of eq">
    <img class="item" src={{image.url}}  (click)="unselect()"/> </div>
 </div>
  <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentInside" *ngFor="let image of images">
      <img class="item" src={{image.url}} (click)="select()"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Here is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U33Ps.png)

Comment: Show your directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only select clicked image.

Change your template to :-

```
<div class="eq">
  <div id="contentInside2" *ngFor="let image of eq; let i=index">
    <img class="item" src={{image.url}}  (click)="unselect(i, image)"/> </div>
 </div>
  <button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<div id="content">
    <div id="contentInside" *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index">
      <img class="item" src={{image.url}} (click)="select(i, image)"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

then typescript method to :-

```
select(index, image) {
    if(this.eq.length === 1) {
       return;
    }
    this.eq.push(image);
    this.images.splice(index, 1);
    localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(this.images));
    localStorage.setItem('eq', JSON.stringify(this.eq));
  }

unselect(index, image) {
    this.eq.splice(index, 1);
    this.images.push(image);
    localStorage.setItem('images', JSON.stringify(this.images));
    localStorage.setItem('eq', JSON.stringify(this.eq));
  }
```